# Is there a way to remove a view from a ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, android-view

I'm working on a Tetris android game. I need to remove some ImageViews from a layout manager. But I can't find any methods in the ViewGroup class to remove views. I know that you can use

```
view.setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE);
```

to make the view invisible, but the view is still here, in the memory, right?
So that will affect the performance, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

What IDE are you using? simply putting `((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).` in the ide should give you the list of all methods.

And ofcourse you have to remove it from the parent viewgroup. that is the need of the method getParent() to get the ViewGroup the view is in, first.

And there is the method `removeView(View view)` right there in the list. Self Explanatory.

Just one thing to remember, you have to call this method from the UIThread. You cannot call this from any other Thread running in the background.

Comment: no, `removeView` is a method of `ViewGroup`, not `ImageView`

Comment: I missed writting getParent(). that was my mistake. I have made the correction.

Answer (score 0):

as you focused to `INVISIBLE` of `VIEW` in your Question,instead of using this you can use `Gone`  of View.so further you can use `gone` in your XML or Java both to a view.

### like in XML

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

### And In Java

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

enjoy your code :)-